# Code Behing update web.config mapping issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, asp.net-3.5

I from the code behind I need to update my web.config. This has never been a problem before, however I am getting an error recently. The errors say "Failed to map the path '/'."
The lines commented out were different variations of what i tried.

```
//Configuration myWebConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Server.MapPath("~"));
        //Configuration myWebConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        //Configuration myWebConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
        Configuration myWebConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(".");
        // update pages theme
        RoleManagerSection section = (RoleManagerSection)myWebConfig.GetSection("system.web/roleManager");
        section.DefaultProvider = "SqlRoleManager";
        section.Providers.Clear();
        ProviderSettings providerSettings = new ProviderSettings();
        providerSettings.Name = "SqlRoleManager";
        providerSettings.Type = "System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider";
        providerSettings.Parameters.Clear();
        providerSettings.Parameters.Add("connectionStringName", "SimpleTickConnection");
        providerSettings.Parameters.Add("applicationName", "TheaterSales");
        section.Providers.Add(providerSettings);
        myWebConfig.Save();
```

Comment: I figured out the reason for the error. After moving the site from my local C: drive to a western digital passport and running the app the error started. 

The line of code below is fine:

            Configuration myWebConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the reason for the error. After moving the site from my local C: drive to a western digital passport and running the app the error started. The line of code below is fine:

```
Configuration myWebConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just at first glance, try making WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("."); point to an actual configuration file such as web.config

WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("web.config");

Make sure to also include the path if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The file path "~/" means the root folder of the Web application. "~" and `null` don't have any meaning to the method; "." means the current (i.e., `bin`) folder.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when I switched from Windows Vista to Windows 7. The default security of Windows 7 caused this because VS didn't have permissions to open the file. Just I restarted Visual Studio as Administrator and it worked, as simple as that.
I hope it helps some other people.