# getting an encrypted connection string from web.config into a classic asp via COM object

Tags: asp-classic

how do we access the web.config connectionstring in the COM object? i cannot get a handle of the web.config file. pls help

i have a classic asp application that needs to encrypt connectionString to the DB. the site currently has a database.asp file that is included in all pages to get a connection. Security team asked us to remove cleartext username, pw and server name. and i am trying to create a COM object to get hold of the web.config file with encrypted cionnectionstring from the application root and then pass back a connString as a variable to use in

```
Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.CursorLocation = 3
set cnStringReader = Server.CreateObject("PropertyReader.FetchProperty")
cnString = cnStringReader.getProperty();
cn.ConnectionString(cnString)
```

but the COM object doesnt find the web.config file. i have saved the COM object in the bin directory of the web application dir. and registered it using gacutil.

please help.

Comment: For classic asp, global settings are in global.asa file. Where web.config is coming from?

Comment: well, we have one aspx file in the web app - so the application is not pure asp. but all other files are asp and include the db.asp. so we have access to .NET functionality but not feasible to convert the whole app to .NET - not sure why it was done that way. :)

Comment: What does it do to find the file? You can find physical path to the file using `Server.MapPath` in ASP.

Comment: here is what it calls:Configuration rootWebConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
            System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connString;

Comment: Possible duplicate [Code Behing update web.config mapping issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447160/code-behing-update-web-config-mapping-issue).

Comment: i dont think so... i keep getting errors like Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0401' 

Expected end of statement 

Dim rootPath As String = Server.MapPath("~") when i add this in my db.asp and pass in to the COM object as a string param.. if i remove the String -         then i get System.Web error '80070057' 

The application relative virtual path '~' is not allowed here. 


-------------^

Answer (score 1):

When ASP CreateObject constructs your COM component it has no way to communicate the web application context to the underlying .NET component.  The component is loaded into a standard default AppDomain just as if you had used CreateObject in a .vbs file and used a scripting shell to execute it.

Hence the standard .NET `OpenWebConfiguration` has no web site context from which it can determine the physical path that "/" represents and therefore what web.config file to load.

If you can resolve the site name (as seen IIS manager) then you can use another overload of `OpenWebConfiguration` which takes the site name as a second parameter.

Whether you can read encrypted connections strings in this way might be another matter, I would doubt it.  I've never tried it but if you can I would question the value of having them encrypted in the first place.  The method by which configuration sections are encrypted would suggest that only the app that registered the encyrption can decyrpt.  Your COM component would not belong to this app.

Personally if you must comply with the "Security Team" boffins you might ask them for their suggestions of how to do it.  My approach would be to use SSPI integrated security so there is no need to store any username/password pairs in any form.

Comment: I did this, (using OpenMappedWebConfiguration instead of OpenWebConfiguration), and I simply had to determine the user the ASP process was running on, and then give it permissions to the .NET config key:  aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR"

Answer (score 0):

From ASP Classic you must read the web.config like an ordinary XML file (i.e. using XmlDocument).  That requires a complete path to the web.config file, which you can get from `Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH")` + "web.config".

Note that since you're reading the web.config like a normal XML file, the encryption utilities that come in WebConfigurationManager don't work.   You'll have to roll your own encryption.

Be careful calling .NET objects wrapped in COM wrappers from ASP Classic.  It can get weird.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/294241/kb937143-breaks-asp-to-net-com-interop

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945701

Comment: You can still use WebConfigurationManager using WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration.  Create a C# COM DLL that wraps this, then create a COM DLL to invoke the C# COM DLL.  Ridiculous, but works for me.  Note that you will have to pass in the site root, since .    I do this from ASP via MyVB6ComComponent.SetWebPagesPath(Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH")), then run MyVB6ComComponent.MyConnectionString.